# how to export javascript function as a module

Tags: javascript, function, import, module, export

I've exported a function and imported it in Javascript, but the only way i can access the functions inside it is by typing it like this:

```
myModule.mainFunc().func1()
```

But what i'm trying to achieve is more like this:

```
myModule.mainFunc.func1()
```

Currently it gives an error if i try to reference to it like this.

I've tried returning the values of the functions as objects but it still needs me to call it as functions.

```
function greet() {

    var hello = () => {
        console.log("hello there");
    };

    var hi = () => {
        console.log("hi there");
    };

    return { hello: hello, hi: hi };  // I've tried this doing it like this 
}

export default {greet};
```

Here's how I'm importing it:

```
import greetings from "./index.js";

greetings.greet().hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference the functions defined inside `greet` function as

```
myModule.mainFunc.func1()
```

because `myModule.mainFunc` is a `greet` function itself. What you want to import is the result of calling `greet` function.

You can avoid invoking the `greet` function manually by making your function an [`IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). Doing this will execute the function as soon as it is defined.

```
const greet = (function() {

    var hello = () => {
        console.log("hello there");
    };

    var hi = () => {
        console.log("hi there");
    };

    return { hello, hi };
})();

export default { greet };
```

Now when you export `greet`, you are not exporting `greet` function, but the result of calling `greet` function which is an object with two functions, `hello` and `hi`.

Answer (score 1):

define greet as an object

```
var greet = {
    hello: () => {
        console.log("hello there");
    },
    hi: () => {
        console.log("hi there");
    },
}
```

and access it like **greet.hello()**

Answer (score 0):

Which environment you're running your code ? If it's NodeJS, make sure it supports ES6 Module as your current style of export and import. Normal NodeJS just supports CommonJS module.